# How to pass in psql password from program on Windows

Tags: postgresql, winapi, psql

I am currently working on PostgreSQL backup and restore functionality for my project. I have read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37154/PostgreSQL-PostGis-Operations  article and followed that approach to do this. It is working fine but recently I have changed the PostgreSQL authentication method to `password` in the `pg_hba.con` file. Hence it started prompting for the password whenever I execute `psql.exe`, `pg_dump.exe`, and `pg_restore.exe`. To provide the password through my project, I have used the "RedirectStandardInput" method. But it did not work and `psql` or `pg_dump` still prompt for the password. However "RedirectStandardOutput" and error methods are working fine.

I went through the PostgreSQL source code and found that `GetConsoleMode` and `SetConsoleMode` are used the remove the echo. I hope ( not sure ) it could be the reason, which is why I am unable to redirect the input.

PostgreSQL source code to prompt the password

```
simple_prompt(const char *prompt, int maxlen, bool echo)
{
    int         length;
    char       *destination;
    FILE       *termin,
               *termout;
#ifdef HAVE_TERMIOS_H
    struct termios t_orig,
                t;
#else
#ifdef WIN32
    HANDLE      t = NULL;
    LPDWORD     t_orig = NULL;
#endif
#endif
    destination = (char *) malloc(maxlen + 1);
    if (!destination)
        return NULL;

    /*
     * Do not try to collapse these into one "w+" mode file. Doesn't work on
     * some platforms (eg, HPUX 10.20).
     */
    termin = fopen(DEVTTY, "r");
    termout = fopen(DEVTTY, "w");
    if (!termin || !termout
#ifdef WIN32
    /* See DEVTTY comment for msys */
        || (getenv("OSTYPE") && strcmp(getenv("OSTYPE"), "msys") == 0)
#endif
        )
    {
        if (termin)
            fclose(termin);
        if (termout)
            fclose(termout);
        termin = stdin;
        termout = stderr;
    }

#ifdef HAVE_TERMIOS_H
    if (!echo)
    {
        tcgetattr(fileno(termin), &t);
        t_orig = t;
        t.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
        tcsetattr(fileno(termin), TCSAFLUSH, &t);
    }
#else
#ifdef WIN32
    if (!echo)
    {
        /* get a new handle to turn echo off */
        t_orig = (LPDWORD) malloc(sizeof(DWORD));
        t = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

        /* save the old configuration first */
        GetConsoleMode(t, t_orig);

        /* set to the new mode */
        SetConsoleMode(t, ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
    }
#endif
#endif
    if (prompt)
    {
        fputs(_(prompt), termout);
        fflush(termout);
    }

    if (fgets(destination, maxlen + 1, termin) == NULL)
        destination[0] = '\0';

    length = strlen(destination);
    if (length > 0 && destination[length - 1] != '\n')
    {
        /* eat rest of the line */
        char        buf[128];
        int         buflen;

        do
        {
            if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), termin) == NULL)
                break;
            buflen = strlen(buf);
        } while (buflen > 0 && buf[buflen - 1] != '\n');
    }

    if (length > 0 && destination[length - 1] == '\n')
        /* remove trailing newline */
        destination[length - 1] = '\0';
#ifdef HAVE_TERMIOS_H
    if (!echo)
    {
        tcsetattr(fileno(termin), TCSAFLUSH, &t_orig);
        fputs("\n", termout);
        fflush(termout);
    }
#else
#ifdef WIN32
    if (!echo)
    {
        /* reset to the original console mode */
        SetConsoleMode(t, *t_orig);
        fputs("\n", termout);
        fflush(termout);
        free(t_orig);
    }
#endif
#endif
    if (termin != stdin)
    {
        fclose(termin);
        fclose(termout);
    }

    return destination;
}
```

Please help me here, how to send the password to `psql` or `pg_dump` via C# code.

Comment: It can be passed in an environment variable named PGPASSWORD, in which case psql or pg_dump won't ask for it.

Comment: You need [.pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Comment: The code is forcing the input to come from the console rather than any redirection, so that the user (and not code) is entering the password.  This is common in many programs that prompt for a password.  As other commenters note, there are workarounds.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, In Windows XP and Windows 7

Comment: Thanks Daniel Vérité, I went through the PGPASSWORD information in this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/libpq-envars.html and this option is recommented. Also, I am running postgres server service running under LOCAL SERVICE account.

Comment: Thanks Milen A. Radev, it is a good option, however it seems to be not that secured since I am running postgres server service running under LOCAL SERVICE account. Hence Windows administrator can able to open this file. Is there a way to secure this file like encrypt it or access denied for any user including administrator.

Comment: Thanks Arx, it is really a good information. I'm looking is there would provide some workarounds

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "postgres server service" but if that's Postgres itself it should be running under its own account. Anyway that has nothing to do with the using of .pgpass.

Comment: "postgres server service" means PostgreSQL server register as a service in windows user account. But if I register this service in LOCAL SERVICE account then it allows administrator can able to view the pgpass file and figured out the password. In order to avoid to view this file, we have to secure this file.                        I went through this article, http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Windows. This approach is also good. But in this approach I just wanna create temporary password file on the fly and set PGPASSFILE env variable and clear it after backup/restore done

Answer (score 0):

Since this is local to the application, the best thing to do is to set %PGPASSWORD% and then psql will not ask for the password.  .pgpass could be used if you wanted to avoid supplying a password at all.  In general you do not want to specify environment variables from the command line since they may show for other users but this is not a concern here.